# git что означает флаг -p?

Tags: веб-программирование, git, github, логирование, git-bash

Есть команда в git bash

```
git log -p -- index.html
```

Что означает флажок `-p`?
Я гуглил - но нигде не нашёл.

Comment: git log -p -- index.html

Comment: то есть в самой документаци https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Основы-Git-Просмотр-истории-коммитов   на строчке "Одним из самых полезных аргументов является -p или --patch"  вы ничего не нашли?

Comment: Мне интересно стало, а какой запрос вы поисковик вбивали? вот я вбил "git log p"  . сразу первый результат дал ответ

Comment: Простой вопрос не есть плохо)

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/57941299/10562663

Comment: @АлексейШиманский думаю, он вводил в гугл -p и это как раз исключило из поиска все варианты с р)))

Comment: Ну и что же ты гуглил, если ответ в первой же ссылке - документации по `git log`? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--p

Comment: Блин, кажется, я понял, что ты гуглил...

Comment: Вот, держи: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1460953/178988.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не получается нагуглить значение флага](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460953/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

`-p` то же самое, как `--patch`.

Английское слово **«patch»** значит **«заплата»**. В давние времена, когда еше не было ни быстрого Интернета, ни больших дисков, вы вместо новых версий больших программ (или других файлов) получали только *«заплату»,* малый кусочек, ***разницу** между новой и старой версией*.

Эту разницу вы применили к вашей большой полной старой версии, «заплатали» ее, чем вы в результате получили полную большую новую версию.

Опция `--patch` (или `-p`) добавлена в команду `git log` значит, что вы хотите кроме информаций об отдельных коммитох *вывести также и «заплаты», т.е. **разницы** между соседними из них.*