# Не получается нагуглить значение флага

Tags: google-search

Ввожу в поиск `git log -p`, но не нахожу релевантных результатов. Что делать?

[image: Скриншот гугла]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [git что означает флаг -p?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460452/git-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3-p)

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, не дубликат. Там вопрос про флаг, а тут про то, как правильно гуглить.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, метка [tag:git] не нужна, потому что вопрос не о гите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использование минуса перед словом [означает](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=ru) отрицание, т. е. запрос `git log -p` - это те страницы, которые содержат `git log`, но не содержат `p`. Чтобы искать что-то, начинающееся с минуса, надо заключать его в кавычки: `git log "-p"`:

[image: скриншот правильного запроса]

Но вообще, для поиска флагов команд гораздо лучше искать документацию по команде, в которой описаны все флаги, поэтому стоит флаг из запроса вообще выкинуть:

[image: скриншот поиска документации]

---

Кстати, аналогичная ситуация с css-свойствами, начинающимися с дефиса - префикс `-webkit` для поиска ничего не меняет:

[image: скриншот неправильного запроса]

[image: скриншот правильного запроса]